# Can MySQL VARCHAR's store any chars?

Tags: mysql, database

Can MySQL VARCHAR's store any char like nulls and newlines?

Comment: NULL is not a character, so no. Newlines are, so yes.
What is the background of your question?

Comment: Oh I always thought null could be represented by 0x00.

Comment: NULL has a special meaning in mySQL: http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/working-with-null.html don't know for sure about null bytes, but I would assume varchars store anything.

Comment: There's a difference between MySQL's "NULL" and the "null character" which is 0x00.

Comment: To be pedantic, the ASCII character with value 0 is called NUL, not null/etc. C (among others) calls this the "null character".

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You should probably use the [`BINARY` and `VARBINARY` data types](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/binary-varbinary.html) for storing strings of non-printable characters, especially if you want strings of single bytes instead of actual text characters (which can be multi-byte).

Answer (score 5):

MySQL can store any chars, but depending on the specified encoding, some characters may be misrepresented if different from your display encoding.

Varchars can contain any chars, even 0x00, since its not a null terminated string, but a length specified string, where the length is specified at the beginning of the string as a 2 or 4 byte value.

I'm not sure about Char columns, but I'm guessing they are null terminated in the sense that the first 0x00 indicates end of string (though storage still takes up the full length).

If you want to store true byte data though, you should use the BLOB type. That is also a length specified type, which is guaranteed to contain whatever data you put into it, and is not affected by encodings at all.